# Vuejs dynamically added ref undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, ref

I'm trying to create a little data editor. A click handler will add an child item inside a parent category like so:

```
methods: {
  addBlank: function(parentKey){
  var obj = {}
  obj.id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999) + 1)
  obj.name = "New Item"
  obj.data1 = 9
  obj.data2 = 9
  obj.data3 = 9

  this.categories[0].children.push(obj)

  console.log("New ref is:",obj.id)
  console.log(this.$refs)  // new $ref is available
  console.log("I can't select it",this.$refs[obj.id]) //returns undefined
  console.log("But I can select others",this.$refs['4214234']) //this is ok
  }
}
```

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/Kay_Wolfe/pen/xJEVRW

How come `this.$refs[obj.id]` return underfined when its there?

Comment: Why use `Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999) + 1)` when the same can be accomplished with `Math.ceil((Math.random() * 99999)`? But more to your question, how do you know that `this.$refs[obj.id]` is defined? It clearly isn't. What does `this.$refs` show when you examine it?

Comment: You need to wait until the ref is actually created using `nextTick`. Here is your pen fixed. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/bjweMa?editors=1010

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A ref is not actually available until the DOM element is generated. That being the case, you have to *wait* until it exists in order to use it.

Typically in Vue, you use [nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) to do that.

```
  addBlank: function(parentKey, event){
      var obj = {}
      obj.id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999) + 1) //(actually a uuid generator is used here)
      obj.name = "New Item"
      obj.data1 = 9
      obj.data2 = 9
      obj.data3 = 9
      
      this.categories[0].children.push(obj)
      
      this.$nextTick(() => {
          console.log("New ref is:",obj.id)
          console.log(this.$refs)  
          console.log("I can't select it",this.$refs[obj.id])
          console.log("But I can select others",this.$refs['4214234'])
      })
  }
```

Here is your [pen updated](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/bjweMa?editors=1010).

Note: one common cause for confusion is that when you log `this.$refs` in your `addBlank` method, it *appears* as though the ref is there when you inspect it in the console. In fact, however, that's not the case. You are logging a reference to the refs object, which *at the time you look at it in the console* has the ref, but *at the time you log it from the function* it does not yet have the ref. Chrome (and possibly other browsers) will show the current state of the reference you logged.